# How to differentiate SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, exception

I need to handle it differently when I catch `SocketTimeoutException`. The only thing I find is to rely on the `getMessage()`. So far, I found two:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Are the messages (connect timed out, Read timed out) hardcoded? Where are they generated? At least any constant values for those messages?

Comment: Very good to ask first! Generally, it's a bad idea to parse the messages. Have you checked if you can use `getCause()` to see what's causing the exception?

Comment: Also, there is a `bytesTransferred`-field as well. Check if this changes depending on the exception cause.

Comment: One is thrown by `connect()` one is thrown by a `read()` ... you never *have* to differentiate between the two.

Comment: We set the socketTimeout when creating socket. We are connecting to a cluster of servers. If connect timed out, meaning the server is bad, we want to mark the server is down. If read timed out, it is the case the server responses slow (due to GC or other recoverable cases), we will try the next server in the cluster. But we don't want to remove the connection pool just yet.

Comment: It's not practical to call getCause() in my cases. We are using third party lib, there could be different places... Also, they might add new method in the later version. It's equally dangerous to rely on the getCause(). I wish there are subclasses of socketTimeoutException which tell the difference.

Comment: Also, beware if you're using an abstraction on top of sockets.  For example, Jersey HTTP client can use the JDK directly, or use Apache HttpClient, which throws its own exception types for timeouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is my claim to fame. Here, we're walking down the StackTrace, looking for the origin-method of the Exception.

```
public class ExceptionOriginTracing {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            originOne();
            originTwo();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // Now for the magic:
            for (StackTraceElement element : e.getStackTrace()){
                if (element.getMethodName().equals("originOne")){
                    System.out.println("It's a read error!");
                    break;
                } else if (element.getMethodName().equals("originTwo")){
                    System.out.println("It's a write error!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void originOne() throws Exception{
        throw new Exception("Read Failed...", null);
    }

    public static void originTwo() throws Exception{
        throw new Exception("Connect failed...", null);
    }
}
```

The difference to parsing the *message* given by the Exception is, that a simple string is more likely to change, than the name of the actual method.

Aside from that, **this is not an optimal solution!** But sadly, there is no optimal solution here.

Also, with this approach, **extra care must be taken when source obfuscation is used**, which will change the method-names and therefor the return value of `getMethodName()`.

---

The right way when *designing* something like this would be to wrap the exception in a new Exception, which provided methods to actually find out the real origin by using a flag or an enum.

Parsing a message/StackTrace always feels dirty and is **subtable to break in future releases!**

Comment: Well, that is probably the best I can do. I do have the full stacktrace. It's not likely those methods name will be changed  java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) and java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method). But meanwhile I don't think the messages will be changed either. "Read time out" and "connect time out". They seem to be in the native code. Notice "Read time out" with capital "R", and "connect time out" with lower case "c". By the way, the socket is inside Thrift transport layer, don't want to mess up with it for sure

Comment: @WeiZhu it's a really messy situation. Maybe a combination of both works best, but than again, both could change in the next release. I would also file a bug-report on the issue-tracker of that particular library, asking to add something to determine what the origin of the exception was.

Answer (score 2):

You can check Socket.isConnected. But since exceptions are thrown by different methods it is better to use two catch blocks with different actions.

```
 try {
       socket.connect(address);
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        throw new SocketConnectionException(e);
    }
    try {
       socket.getInputStream();
       ...
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        throw new SocketReadException(e);
    }
```

Comment: We are using a third party lib which handles the sockets. We are multiple levels above, I don't know what socket method (connect vs read) throws the exception exactly.

Comment: then I do not see good solution for that. As workaround you can check for Exception.getMessage() or Exception.getStackTrace() (second one probably more reliable)

Comment: They do come from different method: for read it comes from:

  Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

  For connect it comes from:

  Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

They come from different methods. 'Connection timed out' happens when calling connect(), implicitly or explicitly; 'read timed out' happens when calling read() or one of its cognates. So you can differentiate just be having two different catch blocks. But in either case you are probably going to close the connection ...

Comment: There's more information in it for a start, but I'm not aware it is an SO crime for the same correct answer to appear more than once per question. If it is, there is an awful log of cleaning up to be done.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late reply.
I just have a boolean flag 'isConnected' initialized to false.
Right after the connect, I set it to true.
If the connect times out, you never get there.

Checking Socket.isConnected after an exception might have been thrown sounds like a bad idea. The socket could by then be closed.

By defining the flag before the `try`, it can be read in `catch` handlers.